# Expression for a result in case

Tags: sql-server, case

I want to give an expression for a result in a `case` expression in SQL Server. When I checked the

Links : [CASE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx) , [EXPRESSIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx). But I'm still confused.

Eg.

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

I want give result_expression as the following example query.

```
select * from mytable where
CASE WHEN col1='12' THEN col2 like '%12%' ELSE col3 like '%12%' END
```

but it giving the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.

Is there any possibilities for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does not have [`BOOLEAN` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)  - at least not exposed, internally it has boolean values that are used in conditions - and a `CASE` expression cannot have a result of such type. See the link above where it explains:

> Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set.

You can rewrite the `WHERE` condition using `AND` and `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ( (col1 = '12')                  AND (col2 LIKE '%12%') ) 
   OR ( (col1 <> '12' OR col1 IS NULL) AND (col3 LIKE '%12%') ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As ypercubeᵀᴹ explained, you cannot return a boolean expression in a THEN clause. Using OR as an alternative to CASE is one way to rewrite your condition.

However, since in the end the chosen column is being checked using the same condition, you can still have a CASE here, but the CASE needs to return either `col2` or `col3` only, and the condition will then be applied to the result of the CASE rather than inside the CASE:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  CASE WHEN col1 = '12' THEN col2 ELSE col3 END LIKE '%12%'
;
```